# Update field on another table when submitting form - django

Tags: django, forms, view

I have a form where adding appointments. I would like to update a field in another table during submission. Let me illustrate:

accounts model (Custom user model)

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    patient_status = (     
        ('No Patient', _('No Patient')),
        ('New Patient', _('New Patient')),
        ('Patient', _('Patient')),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(_('Username'), max_length=50, unique=True)
    ...
    # required
    is_patient = models.CharField(_('Patient'), max_length=20, choices=patient_status)
    ...
```

views.py adding appointment:

```
def add_appointment(request):
    form = AddAppointmentForm(request.POST or None)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            appoint_user = form.cleaned_data.get('user')
            appoint_seat = form.cleaned_data.get('seat')
            appoint_start_appointment = form.cleaned_data.get('start_appointment')
            appoint_end_appointment = form.cleaned_data.get('end_appointment')
            
            # If Appointment already exist 
            if Appointment.objects.filter(user=appoint_user, seat=appoint_seat, start_appointment=appoint_start_appointment, end_appointment=appoint_end_appointment).exists():
                messages.warning(request, "This appointment already exists.")

            else:
                form.save()

                messages.success(request, 'Appointment was added successfully!')
                return redirect('appointments:add_appointment')
    else:
        form = AddAppointmentForm()
```

I would like to update is_patient after is_valid(), something like:

```
patient = Appointment.objects.filter(user=appoint_user).count()
if patient > 0:
  patient.user__is_patient = 'Patient'
  patient.save()
```

How can i access is_patient from Account's table in order to update and also where is the right place to put the code, in the view?

**Update** with appointments model

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    
    APPOINTMENT_STATUS = (
        ('New', _('New')),
        ('Finished', _('Finished')),
        ('Rescheduled', _('Rescheduled')),
        ('Cancelled', _('Cancelled')),
        ('Notshow', _('Notshown')),
    )

    DURATION = (
        ('Notstarted', _('Not Started')),
        ('Checkin', _('Check In')),
        ('TransferToSeat', _('Transfer to Seat')),
        ('Completed', _('Completed')),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    start_appointment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    end_appointment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    appointment_notes = models.TextField(_('Appointment Notes'), max_length=1500, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(_('Appointment Status'), max_length=20, choices=APPOINTMENT_STATUS, default='New')
    duration = models.CharField(_('Duration'), max_length=20, choices=DURATION, default='Not Started')
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(_('Confirmed'), default=False)
    emailed = models.BooleanField(_('Emailed'), default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_('Date Created'), auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Date Updated'), auto_now=True)
```

`Update` after adding code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            appoint_user = form.cleaned_data.get('user')
            appoint_seat = form.cleaned_data.get('seat')
            appoint_start_appointment = form.cleaned_data.get('start_appointment')
            appoint_end_appointment = form.cleaned_data.get('end_appointment')
            
            # If Appointment already exist 
            if Appointment.objects.filter(user=appoint_user, seat=appoint_seat, start_appointment=appoint_start_appointment, end_appointment=appoint_end_appointment).exists():
                messages.warning(request, "This appointment already exists.")

            else:
                patient = Appointment.objects.filter(user=appoint_user)
                if patient.count() > 0:
                    patient[0].user.is_patient = 'Patient'
                    patient.user.save()
                
                else:
                    form.save()
```

Comment: what is appointment models looks like ?

Comment: Thank you for comment! I've updated post with appointments model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
patients = Appointment.objects.filter(user=appoint_user)
if patients.count() > 0:
  for patient in patients:
      patient.user.is_patient = 'Patient'
      patient.user.save()
```

or

```
patients = Appointment.objects.filter(user=appoint_user)
if patients.count() > 0:
    appoint_user.is_patient = 'Patient'
    appoint_user.save()
```

Comment: I get `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'`, i tried like this i've updated post.

Comment: @paniklas have you write exactly what i wrote here ?

Comment: @paniklas you have a typo change this  `patient.user.save()` to `patient[0].user.save()`

Comment: @paniklas is it working ?

Comment: Unfortunately not updated :(. I have `<QuerySet [<Appointment: mariasakka@gmail.com>, <Appointment: mariasakka@gmail.com>, <Appointment: mariasakka@gmail.com>, <Appointment: mariasakka@gmail.com>, <Appointment: mariasakka@gmail.com>, <Appointment: mariasakka@gmail.com>]>`but is_patient not updated, is still 'New Patient'.

Comment: @paniklas i have updated my answer try both answer and let me know if it works.